# FormDataConsumer Within Filter

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin 3.6.2 and I am wondering, can the `<FormDataConsumer />` component be used within a `<Filter />` component? If so, could you please provide an example? If not, how else may I hide and reset one filter based on the use of another filter?

EDIT: I have tried using the FormDataConsumer within a Filter and I could not get it to work. Using dev tools in the browser, it never hits my break point at the if-statement. Code below:

```
<Filter>
 <OtherInputsAsFiltersHere omitForBrevity />
 <FormDataConsumer>
  {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
    if (!check.assigned(formData.sample_code))
      return (
        <DateInput
          source="modified_on_gte"
          label="Modified after"
          {...rest}
        />
      );
  }}
 </FormDataConsumer>
</Filter>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on asking questions, it is encouraged to write your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: @vlizana My attempt was using the FormDataConsumer within a Filter and it did not work. I will edit my question to state that.